# Transform MVC Html.ActionLink to plain HTML with span

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing ASPNET MVC and I would like to use Html.ActionLink
I want however that the final HTML will look like this

from:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

to:

```
<li>
    <a href="layout-variants.html">
        <i class="linecons-desktop"></i>
        <span class="title">Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

How can I transform

Comment: You should use `span` instead of `i` if you want to be more compatible with Html5.  `i` in Html5 is different (symantically) than in was in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of [`Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
        <i class="linecons-desktop"></i>
        <span class="title">Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Url.Action("Index","Home")` is the way around it.

**[See the demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ii5lxI)**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string url)
{
  return "<a href="\" + url +"\"><i class=\"linecons-desktop\"></i><span class=\"title\">Home</span></a>"
}
```

Call from view: @Html.ActionLink("layout-variants.html"), you can change parameter for your project.